# Does air conditioning work harder or just longer?

Tags: air-conditioning

If I don't turn on my air conditioner until the inside temperature is 82 degrees and set it to get it down to 78 degrees, will the a/c work "harder" (whatever that means, i.e., draw more energy/minute) or just longer until it gets to the set temperature?  Mine is a single family home a/c unit by Trane, installed in 2004.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you are going to be away and want to keep the a/c off to save money and not waste electricity, you can shut the a/c off when you leave and turn it on when you get home. The a/c will not "strain itself" to get the temp down to 78 from 82; the a/c will just turn on and run until the temp reaches 78. This will also use less power overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Air conditioners have two states - on or off. Turning the temperature down lower simply causes the AC to run longer; it won't reach the desired temperature any faster.